# How to write Query in SQL Reporting Services query designer to get current sharepoint Login user?

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I Want to create a report using SQL Server Reporting Services. In Visual Studio I created a report to get SharePoint data from a list.

I want to get the current logged in user in SharePoint and check the user permission based on that permission I need to show the data in report. For that how can I write the query in query designer?

I have a user profile area list in that area name should be approved he able to create new contract using that area name.

This is Robert Login he able to see only General, HR, Legal. In above image in user profile area list finance is Denied for robert.

This is George login he able to see only General, HR, Legal, and Finance.

How can I write the query in Query Designer?

I was logged in Robert but in Report it was showing all Contract Areas.

Answer (score 0):

at Dataset Properties > Go to filters >  select the build in field as user ID to get the current login user.

[image]

Comment: Hi,I tried this but this is Won't Work in report all the areas are came in above i added a image

Comment: Hi Qassas did you see that Report image, in that Contract Area dropdown  i want to filter the areas if i logged in Robert in dropdown General,HR,Legal should come.If i logged in George in dropdown General,HR,Legal,Finace should come.How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you tried to update dataset of contract area access (that fill the drop-down list  ) by adding the contract area field then filter username with user ID.

Comment: I need to add any query or just if i add that UserID it should be filter

Comment: I have a two list User Profile Area and Contract Area
ContractArea i need to fetch from Contract area list and current logged in user  permission i need to check in User Profile Area list Isapproved or Denied.

Comment: hi if i did like this it was taking the windows user.Actually i need to filter the contract area based on that sharepoint current logged in user. Its possible ?

Comment: What's the authentication type  it's windows Auth or FBA on your SharePoint ?

Comment: windows authentication

Comment: so the windows user is the current SharePoint login user  !

Comment: In Sharepoint site settings for site i gave  permission to more than 3 users like robert, george,Alex. So using Sign in as Different user option if i logged in alex i will get the current user as alex.Check wheather alex having contract area access to Contract areas then i will fetch those contract area to dropdown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43126/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-kavitha).